# How Do I get the buttons to work? Java Programming

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I created an `Address Book GUI`, I just don't understand How to make the save and delete buttons to work, so when the user fills the text fields they can click save and it saves to the `JList` I have created and then they can also delete from it. How Do I Do this?

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*; 

import java.awt.*;

public class AddressBook {

private JLabel lblFirstname,lblSurname, lblMiddlename,  lblPhone,
lblEmail,lblAddressOne, lblAddressTwo, lblCity, lblPostCode, picture;
private JTextField txtFirstName, txtSurname, txtAddressOne, txtPhone,
txtMiddlename, txtAddressTwo, txtEmail, txtCity, txtPostCode;
private JButton btSave, btExit, btDelete;
private JList contacts;
private JPanel panel;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AddressBook();
}

public AddressBook(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Address Book");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(900,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);


    lblFirstname = new JLabel("First name");
    lblFirstname.setBounds(135, 50, 150, 20);
    Font styleOne = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13);
    lblFirstname.setFont(styleOne);
    panel.add(lblFirstname);
    txtFirstName = new JTextField();
    txtFirstName.setBounds(210, 50, 150, 20);
    panel.add(txtFirstName);

    lblSurname = new JLabel ("Surname");
    lblSurname.setBounds(385,50,150,20);
    Font styleTwo = new Font ("Arial",Font.BOLD,13);
    lblSurname.setFont(styleTwo);
    panel.add(lblSurname);
    txtSurname = new JTextField();
    txtSurname.setBounds(450,50,150,20);
    panel.add(txtSurname);

    lblMiddlename = new JLabel ("Middle Name");
    lblMiddlename.setBounds(620,50,150,20);
    Font styleThree = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblMiddlename.setFont(styleThree);
    panel.add(lblMiddlename);
    txtMiddlename = new JTextField();
    txtMiddlename.setBounds(710,50,150,20);
    panel.add(txtMiddlename);

    lblPhone = new JLabel("Phone");
    lblPhone.setBounds(160,100,100,20);
    Font styleFour = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblPhone.setFont(styleFour);
    panel.add(lblPhone);
    txtPhone = new JTextField();
    txtPhone.setBounds(210,100,150,20);
    panel.add(txtPhone);

    lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
    lblEmail.setBounds(410,100,100,20);
    Font styleFive = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblEmail.setFont(styleFive);
    panel.add(lblEmail);
    txtEmail = new JTextField();
    txtEmail.setBounds(450,100,150,20);
    panel.add(txtEmail);

    lblAddressOne = new JLabel("Address 1");
    lblAddressOne.setBounds(145,150,100,20);
    Font styleSix = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblAddressOne.setFont(styleSix);
    panel.add(lblAddressOne);
    txtAddressOne = new JTextField();
    txtAddressOne.setBounds(210,150,150,20);
    panel.add(txtAddressOne);

    lblAddressTwo = new JLabel("Address 2");
    lblAddressTwo.setBounds(145,200,100,20);
    Font styleSeven = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblAddressTwo.setFont(styleSeven);
    panel.add(lblAddressTwo);
    txtAddressTwo = new JTextField();
    txtAddressTwo.setBounds(210,200,150,20);
    panel.add(txtAddressTwo);

    lblCity = new JLabel("City");
    lblCity.setBounds(180,250,100,20);
    Font styleEight = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblCity.setFont(styleEight);
    panel.add(lblCity);
    txtCity = new JTextField();
    txtCity.setBounds(210,250,150,20);
    panel.add(txtCity);

    lblPostCode = new JLabel("Post Code");
    lblPostCode.setBounds(380,250,100,20);
    Font styleNine = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,13);
    lblPostCode.setFont(styleNine);
    panel.add(lblPostCode);
    txtPostCode = new JTextField();
    txtPostCode.setBounds(450,250,150,20);
    panel.add(txtPostCode);

    //image
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Hassan\\Desktop\\icon.png");
    picture = new JLabel(image);
    picture.setBounds(600,90, 330, 270);
    panel.add(picture);

    //buttons
    btSave = new JButton ("Save");
    btSave.setBounds(380,325,100,20);
    panel.add(btSave);

    btDelete = new JButton ("Delete");
    btDelete.setBounds(260,325,100,20);
    panel.add(btDelete);

    btExit = new JButton ("Exit");
    btExit.setBounds(500,325,100,20);
    panel.add(btExit);
    btExit.addActionListener(new Action());

    //list
    contacts=new JList();
    contacts.setBounds(0,10,125,350);
    panel.add(contacts);

    frame.add(panel); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
//button actions
static class Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame option = new JFrame();
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(option, 
                "Are you sure you want to exit?", 
                "Exit?", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: What problem(s) are you currently encountering?

Comment: The Save and Delete Buttons, I dont know how to make them work.

Comment: Please read [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: your question is too vague.  You already have a listener routine for the exit button; you need listeners for the other two buttons that perform the functionality you want for them.  You need to ask a more specific question to get more help than that.

Comment: I know I need to add the listeners for the other two buttons, I just don`t know the syntax. I am clueless on what I code in the listener

Comment: @حسنChaudhry, mre gave you the answer 14 minutes ago. Have you read the tutorial yet?

Answer (score 3):

Buttons need Event Handlers to work. You have not added any Event Handlers to the Save and Delete buttons. You need to call the addActionListener on those buttons too.
I recommend anonymous inner classes:

```
mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    //do whatever should happen when the button is clicked...
  }

});
```

Comment: What syntax do I use? Any Idea on the code? What do I code where it says //do whatever should happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: In order to answer that, I need to know what should happen when the button is clicked. But your main problem is that you have not added an Action Listener. Without an Action Listener, your buttons just won't do anything.

Comment: mre gave you the answer 10 minutes ago. Did you take the time to read the tutorial?

Comment: Sorry I didn`t understand the tutorial, properly. Basically when the user clicks "Save" all the contact information they have entered is saved to the JList I created called "Contacts", and if they want they can delete the contact from the list using the delete button. thats it.

Comment: OK - so you want to add another entry to the JList. JLIsts are backed by a list model (class DefaultListModel) which actually holds the data. If you call the add() method on the DefaultListModel, you can add an entry. If you have trouble here, I suggest asking another question about JLists and DefaultListModels.

Comment: Thats exactly what the tutorial does and even provides working code you can download. So I'm guessing your really didn't even take the time to read the tutorial and download the code. The tutorial calls the buttons "Hire" and "Fire" (not "Save" and "Delete"). Of course you really shouldn't be using a JList since you have multiple columns to display. You should be using a JTable, but that is another story. First you have to understand the basics of updating a model with data when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `addActionListener` to the buttons `btSave` and `btDelete`.
You could create a anonymous class like this and perform your work there.

```
btSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
   //Do you work for the button here
 }
}


btDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
   //Do you work for the button here
 }
}
```

Edit:

I have an example to which you can refer to and accordingly make changes by understanding it. I got it from a professor at our institute.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TooltipTextOfList{
    private JScrollPane scrollpane = null;
    JList list;
    JTextField txtItem;
    DefaultListModel model;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TooltipTextOfList tt = new TooltipTextOfList();
    }

    public TooltipTextOfList(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tooltip Text for List Item");
        String[] str_list = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        for(int i = 0; i < str_list.length; i++)
            model.addElement(str_list[i]);
        list = new JList(model){
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                int index = locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                if (-1 < index) {
                    String item = (String)getModel().getElementAt(index);
                    return item;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        txtItem = new JTextField(10);
        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(txtItem);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(list);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class MyAction extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            String data = txtItem.getText();
            if (data.equals(""))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter text in the Text Box.");
            else{
                model.addElement(data);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item added successfully.");
                txtItem.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Syntax Do I use for where it says //do your work for the button here? Thats my question

Comment: mre gave you the answer 10 minutes ago. Did you take the time to read the tutorial?

Comment: "What Syntax Do I use" is about as vague as "How do a write a program?". You will need to work out what should happen when the button is pressed. Then, if you have trouble with writing any of the steps, you can ask a more precise question. There are plenty of people willing to help, but we don't know what you want to do.